# What parts of firebase configuration goes in server side and client side in a nodejs web app

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, server

I am running a nodejs app ,express app and have provided a registration and login page for users which send the data to my nodejs server and I then sign in the user with `SignIn with email` methods of firebase.

I am learning firebase and can't get my head around which part of the codes mentioned in the docs are to be included in the views sent to the client and which ones to be included in my nodejs server .

For example :-

- Firebase doc mentions a web app to require("firebase") to use firebase .
- But some pages mention to require("firebase-admin") to work with firebase .
- Also For SignInWithEmailAndPassword method , I am sending some client details to my server and from here in server I am calling the SIgnIn method . Is this the right way to do or should I do all this sign in stuff in the `view` which I send to the client ?

Please explain what parts of code needs to be put in server side and what goes into client side part and explain why ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Firebase Admin SDK is for servers.  That fact is stated very clearly in the title of its [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup).

The [web client setup doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup) suggests that you `require('firebase')` (for node).

You should follow the relevant documentation for the different environments.  Don't assume there to be any overlap.